# tail multiple files and input search term from file, output items searched with filenames

Tags: bash, loops, grep, tail

This currently works ok, want to add the following capabilities:
pipe search items from mygrepitemslist.txt (line by line) instead of my explicitly stating error1 and error2  (bonus if spaces can be include in search)

in other words want something read file mygrepitemslist.txt
and pipe to grep in this code example

instead of in the code below:
grep "error1\|error2"

mygrepitemslist.txt has:
error1
errors
error3 with space
error4 with multiple spaces

Would like to use what I have mainly because I use it for other things and it's familiar, just stuck on how to feed it grep strings from a file then outputting the match with filename

```
tail -Fn0 /var/log/*.log | \
while read line ; do
      echo "$line" | \
      grep "error1\|error2" #pipe mygrepitemslist.txt linebyline here?
      if [ $? = 0 ]
      then
              echo "$line" #how to show error + filename here?
      fi
      done
```

The overall results is:

want to tail/follow multiple files

search for strings read from file called mygrepitemslist.txteach line is search term

output is:
error search with matching file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `-f` option for specifying file with patterns
`tail -Fn0 /var/log/*.log | grep -of mygrepitemslist.txt`

Comment: I replace this line
grep "error1\|error2" #pipe mygrepitemslist.txt linebyline here?

with your suggestion
grep -of mygrepitemslist.txt

but not seeing the filename listed when there is a match

Comment: in your while loop just use grep -f without -o